# Where should i put setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/feritpasha/pen/VwXZpJx)

```
let rock = document.querySelector(".rock-btn");
    let paper = document.querySelector(".paper-btn");
    let scissors = document.querySelector(".scissors-btn");
    
    let select = document.querySelector(".select");
    let computerChoice = document.querySelector(".comp-choice");
    let result = document.querySelector(".result");
    
    rock.addEventListener("click", function press() {
      select.innerHTML = `Select: Rock`;
      let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      let compChoice = "";
      if (randomNum == 0) {
        compChoice = "Rock";
      } else if (randomNum == 1) {
        compChoice = "Paper";
      } else if (randomNum == 2) {
        compChoice = "Scissors";
      }
      result.style.removeProperty("color");
      computerChoice.innerHTML = `Computer choose: ${compChoice}`;
      if (compChoice == "Rock") {
        result.innerHTML = "Result: It's a draw!";
        result.style.color = "#5c3000";
      } else if (compChoice == "Paper") {
        result.innerHTML = "Result: Oh no, You lost!";
        result.style.color = "#8d1d1d";
      } else if (compChoice == "Scissors") {
        result.innerHTML = "Result: Congratulations, You won!";
        result.style.color = "#1e612b";
      }
    });
```

I want to click a rock,paper,scissors and then wait 1 seconds.Basically i want it delay. When i put it normal way it wont work after first time.  I tried to solve on my on  but sadly couldn't. I included codepen so that its easier for you to solve hopefully. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

❌ don't add a `setTimeout` of `1s`, 
✅ but instead, add some nice effect with CSS animations of `1s`.

[image]

---

and for solving the bug

> **bug**: first-time animation work, other times not start animation

you can use a setTimeout of also `1ms`

> 1ms is enough for javascript to delete the class, 
>  so after we successfully deleted that class, now we can re-add it so we have an animation

---

Javascript that I added:

```js
/* THIS IS THE TRICK */
setTimeout(() => {
    result.classList.add("animation")
}, 1); // 1ms of Timeout
```

CSS that I added:

```
/* animation, this is added by javascript */

.animation {
    animation: move 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

---

don't make the user wait for no reason,

 instead make them see some beautiful animation that makes the user think that the site is faster.

 with `setTimeout` the user thinks that the site is a lot slower.

> I also refactored it for you, so you don't need to write multiple time the same code.
>
>  **using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=it) and [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object and [`arrays`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [`switch statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch?retiredLocale=it).**

```js
/* the buttons  */
let rock = document.querySelector(".rock-btn");
let paper = document.querySelector(".paper-btn");
let scissors = document.querySelector(".scissors-btn");

/* elements where we will put a output the outputs */
let select = document.querySelector(".select");
let computerChoice = document.querySelector(".comp-choice");
let result = document.querySelector(".result");

/* all the buttons are one array, 
so we can use them in a forEach loop, 
without repeating a lot the code */
let allButtons = [rock, paper, scissors];

/* this is a array of choices (strings)
it must need to not be modified the order 
1. Rock 2. Paper 3. Scrissors */
let allChoices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

/* the firt {} is for victory, 
the second is for draw, 
the third is for losing */
/* and this array contain all the information you need 
for outputing the victory string with the color in #result */
let allResults = [{
  message: "Result: Congratulations, You won!",
  color: "#1e612b"
}, {
  message: "Result: It's a draw!",
  color: "#5c3000"
}, {
  message: "Result: Oh no, You lost!",
  color: "#8d1d1d"
}];

/* from this array we can see if user win or lose,
it must need to not be modified the order 
1. Rock 2. Paper 3. Scrissors */
let winLoseArray = [{
  toWin: allChoices[2],
  toLose: allChoices[1]
}, {
  toWin: allChoices[0],
  toLose: allChoices[2]
}, {
  toWin: allChoices[1],
  toLose: allChoices[0]
}]

/* forEach loop help us not writing the same code multiple times */
allButtons.forEach((choice, index) => {
  choice.addEventListener("click", () => {
    /* resetting the styles and animations */
    result.classList.remove("animation");
    result.style.removeProperty("color");

    /* random number */
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    /* get the choices of user, and computer */
    let compChoice = allChoices[randomNum];
    let userChoice = allChoices[index];

    /* display the choices in the UI */
    select.innerHTML = `select: ${userChoice}`;
    computerChoice.innerHTML = `Computer choose: ${compChoice}`;

    /* instead of If Else, We Will be using "switch" */
    switch (compChoice) {
      case winLoseArray[index].toWin:
        result.innerHTML = allResults[0].message;
        result.style.color = allResults[0].color;
        break;
      case winLoseArray[index].toLose:
        result.innerHTML = allResults[2].message;
        result.style.color = allResults[2].color;
        break;
      default:
        result.innerHTML = allResults[1].message;
        result.style.color = allResults[1].color;
        break;
    }

    /* THIS IS THE TRICK */
    setTimeout(() => {
      result.classList.add("animation")
    }, 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 25px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
}

p {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 0;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #c2255c;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.rock-btn:hover {
  background-color: #70bdc9;
}

.paper-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f8e9d1;
}

.scissors-btn:hover {
  background-color: #89d0b4;
}

.rock-btn {
  background-color: #4cacbc;
}

.paper-btn {
  background-color: #f6e3c5;
}

.scissors-btn {
  background-color: #6cc4a1;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 15px;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(136, 152, 167);
}


/* animation, this is added by javascript */

.animation {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Rock Paper Scissors!</h1>
  <p class="select">Select:</p>
  <div class="icons">
    <img alt="" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/11/15/672596_open_512x512.png" class="scissors-btn">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/2a/23/f52a2361f819785f37256d8eacd64a0d.png" class="paper-btn">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/256/rock-emoji.png" class="rock-btn">
  </div>
  <p class="comp-choice">Computer choice:</p>
  <p class="result">Result:</p>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```